# How can I use react-router to trigger state changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm still coming to grips with React and react-router, but I'm wondering how to use react-router to simply update application state without re-rendering DOM nodes.

For example, suppose I have:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute screen="main" />
    <Route path="settings" screen="sync" />
    <Route path="overview" screen="overview" />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

I'd like to re-use react-router's matching but simply update the App component's current screen.

The reason is that suppose in the above example I have three screens arranged horizontally with only one visible at a time. When the route changes I want to animate in the appropriate screen. If I do that by assigning a component to each route, react-router doesn't render the other screens until the route matches, and there's a noticeable lag for the screen to slide in.

However, if I keep all three screens in the DOM and simply toggle state to trigger CSS transitions there is no lag (since, with appropriate use of `will-change`, the browser can pre-render the off-screen layer).

I've tried half a dozen ways of achieving this but they're all very hacky or involve duplicating the matching code somewhat. What am I doing wrong?

Also, I'd like to avoid adding something like Redux just to fix this if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want something similar to [Spectacle](http://stack.formidable.com/spectacle/#/?_k=pmfc27)?

In your case I would place all the screens as children of the `App` component, and use react-router's params to know which screen you're on.

`<Route path="/(:screen)" component={App}>`

It will be avaialble as a prop to the `App` component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount () {
    this.props.params.screen
  }
}
```

More about route params at [react-router/injected-props](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#injected-props)

If you're having trouble with re-rendering you can use the component lifecycle method [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate). Returning `false` in this method will prevent the component from re-rendering and you'll have the new props (which also include the route params).

```
class App extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps) {
    nextProps.params.screen
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I never thought of parameterizing the screen at the top-level.
I'll look into shouldComponentUpdate too. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks from me too :) ... with this difference that I'm using "componentDidUpdate" ... but the goal is achieved thanks to you ;)